# how to simplify animation jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jQuery code. How can I make it more simple?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.button1').hover(function() {
    $(".box-1").stop().animate({bottom:'0'});
     $('.dul-1').stop().animate({top:'0px'});
},
function () {
$(".box-1").stop().animate({bottom:'-100px'});
    $('.dul-1').stop().animate({top:'-100px'});
}
);


 $('.button2').hover(function() {
    $(".box-2").stop().animate({bottom:'0'});
     $('.dul-2').stop().animate({top:'0px'});
},
function () {
$(".box-2").stop().animate({bottom:'-100px'});
    $('.dul-2').stop().animate({top:'-100px'});
}
);  });
```

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/9xlog/nqgkpqv6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqgkpqv6/2/)
have added data-index attribute to button class div. and get index on hove event of button.with index you can dynamically create class name of  .box-1 and .dul-1 or 2

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var index  = ''
   $('.button').hover(function() {
      index = $(this).data('index');
      $(".box-"+index).stop().animate({bottom:'0'});
      $('.dul-'+index).stop().animate({top:'0px'});
   },
   function ()  {
      $(".box-"+index).stop().animate({bottom:'-100px'});
      $('.dul-'+index).stop().animate({top:'-100px'});
    }
   );
});
```